# Issue with pow and round - answers are not equivalent

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, pow

I'm having an issue creating a function that checks if a root can be simplified. In this example, I'm trying to simplify the cube root of 108, and the first number that this should work for is 27.

In order to do this, I am calling `pow()` with the number being the index (in this case, 27), and the power being (1/power), which in this instance is 3. I then compare that to the rounded answer of pow(index,(1/power)), which should also be 3.

Included is a picture of my problem, but basically, I am getting two answers that are equivalent to 3, yet my program is not recognizing them as equal. It seems to be working elsewhere in my program, but will not work here. Any suggestions as to why?

```
int inside = insideVal;
int currentIndex = index;
int coeff = co;
double insideDbl = pow(index, (1/(double)power));
double indexDbl = round(pow(index,(1/(double)power)));
cout<<insideDbl<< " " << indexDbl <<endl;
//double newPow = (1/(double)power);
vector<int> storedInts = storeNum;
if(insideDbl == indexDbl){
    if(inside % currentIndex == 0){
        storedInts.push_back(currentIndex);
        return rootNumerator(inside/currentIndex, currentIndex, coeff, power, storedInts);
    }
    else{
        return rootNumerator(inside, currentIndex + 1, coeff, power, storedInts);
    }
}
else if(currentIndex < inside){
    return rootNumerator(inside, currentIndex + 1, coeff, power, storedInts);
}
```

I tried to add a picture, but my reputation apparently wasn't high enough. In my console, I am getting "3 3" for the line that reads `cout<<insideDbl<< " " << indexDbl <<endl;`

EDIT:

Alright, so if the answers aren't exact, why does the same type of code work elsewhere in my program? Taking the 4th Root of 16 (which should equal 2) works using this segment of code:

```
    else if( pow(initialNumber, (1/initialPower)) == round(pow(initialNumber,(1/initialPower)))){
        int simplifiedNum = pow(initialNumber, (1/initialPower));
        cout<<simplifiedNum;
        Value* simplifiedVal = new RationalNumber(simplifiedNum);
        return simplifiedVal;
    }
```

despite the fact that the conditions are exactly the same as the ones that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Obligatory link (required for every question related to issues comparing floating point values for equality):  
  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Floating point numbers are not real numbers and output precision is not neccessarily equal to internal precision.

Comment: @Deduplicator so I added an edit that further explains why I'm confused. is it just that, coincidentally, when this segment of code is called, they're equivalent, but when the other one is, they aren't? Because I have this called multiple times and it seems to be working, but obviously if it's up to essentially chance, I may need to find a different way to do this.

Comment: Yes it's chance, although the chances might be greater when you're using powers of 2. Rule of thumb: never *ever* compare two floating point values for equality, use a tolerance instead. And always be aware that output functions apply rounding, it would take 53 digits to get an exact value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are a victim of finite precision floating point arithmetic.

**What happened?**

This `if(insideDbl == indexDbl)`, is very dangerous and misleading. It is in fact a question whether (*Note: I made up the exact numbers but I can give you precise ones*) `3.00000000000001255` is the same as `2.999999999999996234`. I put 14 `0`s and 14 `9`s. So technically the difference goes beyond 15 most significant places. This is important.

Now if you write `insideDbl == indexDbl`, the compiler compares the binary representantions of them. Which are clearly different. However, when you simply print them, the default precision is like 5 or 6 significant digits, so they get rounded, and seem to be the same.

**How to check it?**

Try printing them with:

```
typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl_limits;
cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10);
cout << "Does " << insideDbl  << " == " << indexDbl << "?\n";
```

This will set the precision, to the number of digits, the are necessary to differentiate two numbers. Please note that this is higher than the guaranteed precision of computation! That is the root of confusion.

I would also encourage reading  [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). Especially about `digits10`, and `max_digits10`.

**Why sometimes it works?**

Because sometimes two algorithms will end up using the same binary representation for the final results, and sometimes they won't.

Also `2` can be a special case, as I believe it can be actually represented exactly in binary form. I think (but won't put my head on it.) all powers of 2 (and their sums) can be, like `0,675 = 0,5+0,125 = 2^-1 + 2^-3`. But please don't take it for granted unless someone else confirms it.

**What can you do?**

Stick to the precise computations. Using integers, or whatever. Or you could assume that everything `3.0 +/- 10^-10` is actually 3.0 (epsilon comparisons), which is very risky, to say the least, when you do care about precise math.

**Tl;dr:** You can never compare two `float`s or `double`s for equality, even when mathematically you can prove the mentioned equality, because of the finite precision of computations. That is, unless you are actually interested in the same binary representation of the value, as opposed to the value itself. Sometimes this is the case.

Comment: 1) Any integer whose magnitude is less than 2^53 can be represented precisely as a double. 2) Any power of 2, positive or negative, in the exponent range, can also be represented precisely. 3) The product of a precise integer and a precise power of 2 is also precisely representable, unless its too big. 4) There's no such thing as two floating point representations which are "technically the same" except for +0/-0. 5) However, the advice is not bad.

Comment: Those are the parts, where I said don't take my word for granted. Thanks for the clarifications. Regarding 4. They are the same within the precision given by standard. You can say that, when comparing values with uncertainties. Maybe I used bad wording, I should have said, "two different representations of a number have the same value within `double` precision". Would you agree on this? Not sure why I got -1 though, but what evs. Your comment makes great addendum to parts which I was not very sure of.

Comment: The IEEE-754 standard does not include any wording which could be interpreted as meaning that floating point numbers are not precisely what they claim to be. That is, a floating point number (in any IEEE-754 format) represents some precise rational number. *Computations* may need to be adjusted, since the precise result may not be representable, but for primitive operators other than binary-to-decimal conversion, the implementation is required to round precisely. So I have no idea where you got that "14.7 digits" from. Citations please (and a precise quote would be handy, too).

Comment: @rici 14.7 is my mistake. It should be "~15.95". I meant this: *"This gives from 15–17 significant decimal digits precision. If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision representation and then converted back to a string with the same number of significant digits, then the final string should match the original; and if an IEEE 754 double precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits and then converted back to double, then the final number must match the original."*

Comment: @rici Sources: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#cite_note-whyieee-1), [cited document](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF). But I remvoed this paragraph as I don't believe it serves any purpose in the context of the question. I meant that when you are thinking in a decimal representation you can only be sure what you are putting into a `double` will be precisely this number only up to 15 significant digits.

Comment: Yes, as I said, that has nothing to do with the precision of representation, but rather with the accuracy of presentation. That is, it is not discussing some abstract "guaranteed precision" of the numbers, because any floating point value is actually precise, or of computation, because the accuracy of computation is based on the binary representation. It is discussing the accuracy of binary<->decimal conversion; nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you'll do better by computing the prime factorisation of `insideVal` and taking the product of those primes that appear in a multiple of the root.

For example

108 = 2<sup>2</sup> × 3<sup>3</sup>

and hence

<sup>3</sup>√108 = 3 × <sup>3</sup>√2<sup>2</sup>

and

324 = 2<sup>2</sup> × 3<sup>4</sup>

and hence

<sup>3</sup>√324 = 3 × <sup>3</sup>√(2<sup>2</sup> × 3)

You can use [trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) to construct the factorisation.

**Edit** A C++ implementation

First we need an integer overload for `pow`

```
unsigned long
pow(unsigned long x, unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long p = 1;

    while(n!=0)
    {
        if(n%2!=0) p *= x;
        n /= 2;
        x *= x;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Note that this is simply the [peasant algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication) applied to powers.
Next we need to compute the prime numbers in sequence

```
unsigned long
next_prime(const std::vector<unsigned long> &primes)
{
    if(primes.empty()) return 2;

    unsigned long p = primes.back();
    unsigned long i;

    do
    {
        ++p;
        i = 0;
        while(i!=primes.size() && primes[i]*primes[i]<=p && p%primes[i]!=0) ++i;
    }
    while(i!=primes.size() && primes[i]*primes[i]<=p);

    return p;
}
```

Note that `primes` is expected to contain all of the prime numbers less than the one we're trying to find and that we can quit checking once we reach a prime greater than the square root of the candidate `p` since that could not possibly be a factor.
Using these functions, we can calculate the factor that we can take outside the root with

```
unsigned long
factor(unsigned long x, unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long f = 1;

    std::vector<unsigned long> primes;
    unsigned long p = next_prime(primes);

    while(pow(p, n)<=x)
    {
        unsigned long i = 0;
        while(x%p==0)
        {
            ++i;
            x /= p;
        }
        f *= pow(p, (i/n));

        primes.push_back(p);
        p = next_prime(primes);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Applying this to your example

```
std::cout << factor(108, 3) << std::endl; //output: 3
```

gives the expected result. For another example, try

```
std::cout << factor(3333960000UL, 4) << std::endl; //output: 30
```

which you can confirm is correct by noting that

3333960000 = 30<sup>4</sup> × 4116

and checking that 4116 doesn't have any factor that is a power of 4.